# 3 digit Prime Palindrome Numbers.

Tags: number-theory, palindrome

Question. How many three digit palindrome number are prime?

Ans. Any 3 digit palindrome number is of type "aba" where b can be chosen from the numbers 0 to 9 and a can be chosen from 1 to 9. So the totality of these type of numbers are 10×9=90. 
But, how can I find the prime numbers out of these 90s……!!!
Thankyou.

Comment: Obviously you can restrict the values of $a$ to $(1,3,7,9)$ (remove multiples of $2$ and $5$), and then also guard against a few obvious factors like $3$. But the tools are available to easily find the 15 possibilities.

Comment: 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$90$ is not so many, so you can just check them.  We know that primes end in $1,3,7,$ or $9$, so $a$ must be one of those and you are down to $40$.  You should be able to find a condition on $a,b$ that will guarantee that $aba$ is divisible by $3$, which will cut the number down a few more.

Comment: Thank you @ Ross Millikan...But what would be in the case of a larger palindromes (Such as 4 digit or 5 digit)...Is there any method to find the primes out of them or I have to check each Palindrome if it is a prime or not....??

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh Interesting...there does not appear to any 4 digit prime palindromes.  I suspect that has something to do with the fact that there are no two digit prime palindromes except for $11$.

Comment: Aside from the ones you can eliminate with divisibility tests (which is how we know primes end in $1,3,7,9$) you just have to try them.   There is little relationship between primes and base $10$ representations aside from factors of $2$ and $5$, so the numeric representation doesn't help much in assessing primality.  It is not nearly as important that the string "7919" represents a prime in base 10 as that the number it represents is prime.

Comment: There are no palindromic primes with an even number of digits except $11$.  $11$ divides every palindromic number with an even number of digits.  The classic test for divisibility by $11$ proves this.  You add the numbers in the odd digit positions and subtract the ones in the even positions.  For a palindrome this will always be zero, which shows the number is divisible by $11$

Answer (score 2):

You need to check only numbers of the form $xyx$, where $x\in[1,3,7,9]$ and $y\in[0,\dots,9]$.

This comes down to $4\cdot10=40$ numbers.

You can reduce this even further, by checking only numbers of the following forms:

- $1y1$, where $y\in[0  ,2,3  ,5,6  ,8,9]$ (the rest are divisible by $3$)
- $3y3$, where $y\in[  1,2  ,4,5  ,7,8  ]$ (the rest are divisible by $3$)
- $7y7$, where $y\in[0  ,2,3  ,5,6  ,8,9]$ (the rest are divisible by $3$)
- $9y9$, where $y\in[  1,2  ,4,5  ,7,8  ]$ (the rest are divisible by $3$)

This comes down to $7+6+7+6=26$ numbers.

---

The remaining numbers can be tested only against $7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31$:

- $121$ is divisible by $11$
- $161$ is divisible by $7$
- $323$ is divisible by $17$
- $343$ is divisible by $7$
- $707$ is divisible by $7$
- $737$ is divisible by $11$
- $767$ is divisible by $13$
- $949$ is divisible by $13$
- $959$ is divisible by $7$
- $979$ is divisible by $11$
- $989$ is divisible by $23$

So $11$ palindromes are not prime, which leads to $26-11=15$ prime palindromes.